# jQuery scroll to top of iframe parent

Tags: jquery, scroll

I have an iFrame with a feedback form in it.  After the user clicks submit, I want use parent window to scroll to the top.  I know I can scroll to the top of a page with:

```
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 'slow');
```

However, this will only scroll the contents of the iframe, not the parent page.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Give a try for this one :

```
window.parent.$("body").animate({scrollTop:0}, 'slow');
```

Comment: I know this question was answered almost a year ago, but when I try this, I get the following error: `TypeError: Property '$' of object [object DOMWindow] is not a function.` Using the JavaScript console in Google Chrome, I can see a `$` function defined on `window.parent` but when I drill into it, it says it's undefined. Is there a reason why this answer may no longer be valid?

Comment: You don't need jquery, if you don't care about animation, use window.parent.window.scrollTo(0,0); They must be in the same domain due to security reason.

Answer (score 12):

This seems to do the trick as well:

`$('html, body', window.parent.document).animate({scrollTop:0}, 'slow');`

The [second parameter](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) to `$` is the context to search in.

Answer (score 8):

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        FB.Canvas.scrollTo(0,0);
        FB.Canvas.setSize({width: 760, height:$('body').height()+20});
    });

    function scrollTo(x,y) {
        $("body").append('<iframe id="scrollTop" style="border:none;width:1px;height:1px;position:absolute;top:-10000px;left:-100px;" src="http://static.ak.facebook.com/xd_receiver_v0.4.php?r=1#{%22id%22%3A0%2C%22sc%22%3Anull%2C%22sf%22%3A%22%22%2C%22sr%22%3A2%2C%22h%22%3A%22iframeOuterServer%22%2C%22sid%22%3A%220.957%22%2C%22t%22%3A0}[0%2C%22iframeInnerClient%22%2C%22scrollTo%22%2C{%22x%22%3A'+x+'%2C%22y%22%3A'+y+'}%2Cfalse]" onload="$(\'#scrollTop\').remove();"></iframe>');
    }
</script>
```

Comment: FB.Canvas. scrollTo(0,0); this is very helpful. searching for days. thanks

Comment: This answer lacks a lot explanation... it's Facebook app specific. But I was trying to solve this issue for an iFrame (canvas) Facebook application, so `FB.Canvas.scrollTo(0,0);` was just what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Within the Iframe page.

```
window.parent.ScrollToTop(); // Scroll to top function
```

On The parrent page:

```
window.ScrollToTop = function(){
  $('html,body', window.document).animate({
    scrollTop: '0px'
  }, 'fast');
};
```

Answer (score 1):

`<body onLoad="window.parent.scroll(0,0);">`

In the body of the iframe's html page

Its as simple as you can do!