# Scroll down to section from an iframe

Tags: jquery, html, css, iframe

How do I scroll to a section in a parent page from a link in an iframe, using jquery?

This question shows how to scroll to the top, but I want to scroll **down** to a section below the iframe, not to the top of the parent. [jQuery scroll to top of iframe parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3805243/jquery-scroll-to-top-of-iframe-parent)

Please could someone help?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can put together the idea from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5013281/need-javascript-to-auto-scroll-to-the-target-html-element-after-page-loads) with the one you reference.

```
<h1 id="target">Scroll to here</h1>

window.parent.document.getElementById("target").scrollIntoView(true);
```